# Prepositional phrase order

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> I sit in the hospital on the chair.

It means I sit on the hospital’s chair. Does “on the chair” need to be moved right after “sit”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - I sit in the hospital on the chair.
> - I sit on the chair in the hospital.

Both of these are grammatical, and in this case they have pretty much the same meaning. The first emphasizes the hospital a bit more, the second emphasizes the chair. But this is a very slight difference.